# Weird Javascript error

Tags: javascript

I have a html page which has this js:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() { 
        BOOKS.init({ 
                xmlPath : "http://localhost/project/books.xml", 
                imgPath : "http://localhost/project/img/", 
                perView : 6 
        }); 
)}; 
</script>
```

However "**$(fun**" decided to disappear and become:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
ction() { 
        BOOKS.init({ 
                xmlPath : "http://localhost/project/books.xml", 
                imgPath : "http://localhost/project/img/", 
                perView : 6 
        }); 
)}; 
</script>
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? You mean that your .html file looks like the first block of code, but then when you view source in the live view it looks like the second block of code?

Comment: yes for the 1st block of codes i coded in Dreamweaver. However when I view via the explorer and view source, the 2nd block of codes appeared.

Comment: Perhaps it's a "dreamweaver thing". Can you view the .html in your browser as opposed to the dreamweaver live view?

Comment: I this a caching bug?  Maybe you need to clear your browser cache and reload the page.

Comment: yes. i did view it on a browser. similar result from second block of codes.

Comment: I wish I could downvote dreamweaver

Answer (score 1):

Jian, You have the syntex error in your code.
Your closing brace of function() is before then closing brace of $. Use the below code. I have   edited it.

```
$(function() { 
    BOOKS.init({ 
            xmlPath : "http://localhost/project/books.xml", 
            imgPath : "http://localhost/project/img/", 
            perView : 6 
    }); 
});
```

Use firebug for javascript :)